# AngularJS: Why is $http response.data an object, when php returns a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ajax

I have an  ajax call to php.

The angular is straight forward:

```
$http( { // ...            
       }
      )
  .then( function cf_handle_success( argo_response ) 
           { console.log( argo_response.data ) ; // --> [object Object]
           } ,
         // ...
       ) ;
```

The php is straight forward:

```
$lvl = array( "prop_A" => "value_A" , ... ) ;
echo json_encode( $lvl  , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT ) ;
```

Why isn't `argo_response.data` a JSON string?

It is true that once the client receives the returned info from php I will need it to be converted into object via `(JSON.parse(my_jsonString);)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Angular is parsing it for you automatically, like jQuery and several other libs do.

From the [`$http` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations):

> **Default Transformations:**
>
> ...
>
> Response transformations (`$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` and `$http.defaults.transformResponse`):
>
> - If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations section below).
> - **If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser.**

*(my emphasis on the last bullet)*